# Activity sliding animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I want to add sliding animation from bottom to top when opening new activity, and when I go back to a previous one, I want an animation from top to bottom. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it after calling **startActivity()**:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Your code will be like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: And how can I do that if user goes back to previous activity by pressing back button?

Comment: @DawidCyron when you call this method after startActivity(), this receive two animations, the first one is for enter transation, the second is the exit transation.

`overridePendingTransition(enter_animation, exit_animation);`